# NHibernate one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, automapper

I am having class which contain property which is list of some other class.
 I want to map this class to another class in queryable extension.

```
AutoMappper.CreateMap<Department1, Department2>()
AutoMapper.CreateMap<Employee1, Employee2>()
var employee1 =_session.Query<Employee1>();
employee1.Project().To<Employee2>();
```

It give error 'Could not excecute query Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.'
select employee1_.Id as col_0_0_, employee1_.Name as col_1_0_, (select Department1_.Id, Department1_.Name from Department.Department Department1_) as col_2_0_ from [Emplolyee].[Employee] Employee1_

As same solution works on Enumerable case
 mapper.Map(employee1); 
Below are the classes.

```
public class Employee1
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<Department1>{get;set;}
}

public class Department2
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int Name {get;set;}
}

public class Employee2
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<Department2>{get;set;}
}

public class Department1
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int Name {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: I think its a bug of NHibernate. For the class having nested generic object. I won't work for Queryable.

Comment: You don't show any NHibernate mapping code or any use of IQueryable, how did you determine there a bug in NHibernate?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : The exception 'Could not excecute query Only one expression can be specified in the select list when ...   '   i had given the details their. So it can be NHibernate or AutoMapper problem. It is creating wrong query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use NHibernate 4, which has some limited ability to project nested collections.

Comment: That simply sounds interesting. Wouldn't you share more details?