# Why Automapper Queryable Extension create wrong query

Tags: c#, automapper

When the class contain list of some other class.
And i create Queyable extension for base class to map
then it create wrong query. It takes all the parameters of nested object in select clause.

Eg

```
Emp{
    int Id{get;set;}
    string Name{get;set;}
    List<Dept>{get;set;}
}

CreateMap<Source.Emp,Dest.Emp>()
CreateMap<Source.Dept,Dest.Dept>()
sourceEmp.Project().To<Dest.Emp>()
```

the querya generate is '

```
select id,name,(select id,name from Department) from Employee'
```

I want

```
'select id, name , dept.Id, dept.Name from Employee left outer join Department ..... '
```

Comment: Because you created the wrong mapping. Your code maps Employee to itself, Department to itself and tries to create a projection that includes both.  If you want a specific answer though, you'll have to post *the actual code* for both classes and the mapping.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : both class are in different namespace.

Comment: This is unimportant. Your code is creating a mapping from Emp to Emp, not Empt to Dept. Anyway, without any code it's impossible to help more

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28021423/nhibernate-one-expression-can-be-specified-in-the-select-list-when-the-subquery

Comment: The question you posted is unrelated. Your Automapper code maps each class to itself, not each other.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Its a  mapping between entity class and View Model

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69183/discussion-between-hemant-malpote-and-panagiotis-kanavos).